# React. UserContext is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have this error

Uncaught TypeError: UserContext is not a function
at UserAuth (AuthContext.js:26:1)
at Signup (Signup.js:11:1)

AuthContext.js

```
import { createContext } from 'react'
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged
} from "firebase/auth"
import { auth } from "../firebase"

const UserContext = createContext()

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children})  => {

  const createUser = (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  }

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={createUser}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return UserContext(UserContext)
}
```

Signup.js

```
const {createUser} = UserAuth()
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `UserContext` which is not a function. What you are looking for is `React.useContext()`. In your example

```js
export const UserAuth = () => {
  return React.useContext(UserContext);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the context in the App.js file? Using context just requires importing it and calling it!

ALso, check this article, https://dev.to/dancurtis/learn-to-usecontext-with-hooks-in-3-minutes-4c4g

It is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating that `UserContext` is not a function and you are calling `UserContext` as a function at this part of your code:

```
export const UserAuth = () => {
  return UserContext(UserContext)
}
```

From your code, I'm assuming that you're trying to export the UserContext to use it in other places.

In this case, you should export the UserContext variable first:

```
export const UserContext = createContext()
```

And in the other pages you can use `React.useContext`, like this:

```
import { UserContext } from "AuthContext.js";

const MyComponent = () => {
    const userContext = React.useContext(UserContext);
    userContext.createUser('email@domain.com', 'password');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const UserAuth = () => {
   return UserContext(UserContext)
}
```

Your code doesn't work as you call UserContext which is a Context Object.

This code should work:

```
export const UserAuth = () => {
   return UseContext(UserContext)
}
```

Comment: The solution that you've provided is the same as what is already included in the question.  Was this a mistake?